# findOne in mongoose returns empty object and then the correct one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, web, mongoose

I am trying to add an existing recipe to a user from my database, here are my functions:

```
exports.addRecipeToUser =  (user,recipeName) => {

  let recipe =  this.findRecipe(recipeName);
  console.log("i am in model",recipe)

  User.updateOne({username: user},{ $push: { recipes: recipe} },function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });

}

exports.findRecipe = async (recipeName) => {

  Recipe.findOne({name: recipeName}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err){
        return err;
    }
    else{
      console.log("testing 1111111111",docs);
        return docs;
    }
  });
  }
```

when I call this function like this :

```
model.addRecipeToUser("a@b.com","pancake");
```

this is what I get:

```
i am in model Promise { undefined }
testing 1111111111 {
  categories: [ 'Dessert' ],
  _id: 60cb54b80790970dab918bbc,
  name: 'pancake',
  img: 'https://www.auxdelicesdupalais.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/pancakes-fluffy-2.jpg',
  description: 'e2e2e2 dewf; ewk  kks  lel f ',
  ingredients: [
    {
      _id: 60cb54bc0790970dab918bbe,
      name: 'cheese',
      quantity: 2,
      unit: ''
    }
  ],
  steps: [
    {
      _id: 60cb54bf0790970dab918bc0,
      description: 'e2e2e2 dewf; ewk  kks  lel f ',
      img: 'https://www.auxdelicesdupalais.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/pancakes-fluffy-2.jpg'
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

In robo 3T, the value that is saved is Null,
I tried without the async and I get the same result, I looked at other questions and tried the answers and it is still undefined.
why is findRecipe Called after the console.log?
what can I do to get the correct object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing callbacks with async/await, and using async/await not properly.

```js
exports.addRecipeToUser = async (user,recipeName) => {
 try {
    const recipe = await Recipe.findOne({name: recipeName});
    await User.updateOne({username: user}, { $push: { recipes: 
     recipe} });
 } catch(error) {
        console.error(error)
 }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't I add a callback in case of an error ? Thank you for you answer BTW

Comment: no, you use try/catch with async/await, and .catch with Promises

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out, I hope this will help someone:

```
exports.addRecipeToUser = async  (user,recipeName) => {

  let recipe = await  Recipe.findOne({name: recipeName}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err){
        return err;
    }
    else{
      console.log("testing 1111111111",docs);
        return docs;
    }
  });
  console.log("i am in model",recipe)

  User.updateOne({username: user},{ $push: { recipes: recipe} },function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
  });

}
```